# BOT doesn't pick the knowledgebase

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I was customizing a virtual assistant based on the VirtualAssistantTemplate provided in VS2019. As per the Microsoft docs I have made the changes to the qnamaker knowledge base. Then ran the update cognitive models script. Checked that the faq.qna file has the changes. But when I run the VA it doesn't pick from the FAQ.qna it is picking from MainResponses.lg. How do I make the FAQ.qna be picked instead?

FAQ.qna - one of the change done through qnamaker.ai

````
##? What times is the doctor?

```markdown
The doctor is available from Monday through Saturday from 5 pm to 9 pm
````

```
General.lu - changes are done through luis.ai website

## Appointment
- appointment of doctor
- can I come and see the doctor next week?
- can I get an appointment of doctor this week
- can I get appointment of the doctor today
- can I get appointment of the doctor today evening
- can I get appointment of doctor tomorrow
- can I get appointment of doctor tomorrow morning
- doctor available today
- Is the doctor available tomorrow?
- is a doctor available?
- need the appointment of doctor
- what is the availability of the doctor?
- what time I can see the doctor today
- what time I can visit the doctor tomorrow
- when can I visit the doctor?

maindialog.cs where the dispatch has been initialized 

protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var activity = innerDc.Context.Activity;

            // Get cognitive models for the current locale.
            var localizedServices = _services.GetCognitiveModels();

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.Text))
            {
                // Run LUIS recognition and store result in turn state.
                var dispatchResult = await localizedServices.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync<DispatchLuis>(innerDc.Context, cancellationToken);
                innerDc.Context.TurnState.Add(StateProperties.DispatchResult, dispatchResult);

                if (dispatchResult.TopIntent().intent == **DispatchLuis**.Intent.**l_General**)
                {
                    // Run LUIS recognition on General model and store result in turn state.
                    var generalResult = await localizedServices.LuisServices["General"].RecognizeAsync<GeneralLuis>(innerDc.Context, cancellationToken);
                    innerDc.Context.TurnState.Add(StateProperties.GeneralResult, generalResult);
                }

                // Check for any interruptions
                var interrupted = await InterruptDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);

                if (interrupted)
                {
                    // If dialog was interrupted, return EndOfTurn
                    return EndOfTurn;
                }
            }

            // Set up response caching for "repeat" functionality.
            innerDc.Context.OnSendActivities(StoreOutgoingActivitiesAsync);
            if (innerDc.ActiveDialog.Id == FaqDialogId)
            {
                // user is in a mult turn FAQ dialog
                var qnaDialog = TryCreateQnADialog(FaqDialogId, localizedServices);
                if (qnaDialog != null)
                {
                    Dialogs.Add(qnaDialog);
                }
            }

            return await base.OnContinueDialogAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
        }

Please let me know how to fix this problem and move forward.
```

Comment: The only responses for QnA in mainresponses.lg is the NoMatch, and AdaptiveLearning answers. Which set are you getting? Is it returning a 'NoMatch' response every time?

Comment: Yes, it is returning 'NoMatch' response for all the new queries.